# Nativescript 4.1 app-root with drawer and login page

Tags: nativescript

I have a 4.1.2 NS application with Typescript.  I wanted to take advantage of the new app-root framework by using a drawer as suggested in https://github.com/NativeScript/template-drawer-navigation

The issue I am having is that our app needs to display a login page first where the drawer is not needed and should not show.

What is the best way to accomplish this in NS 4.1.2?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The approach I've taken in [this POC application](https://github.com/NickIliev/nativescript-ng-cosmos) is to create [a root sidedrawer](https://github.com/NickIliev/nativescript-ng-cosmos/blob/master/app/app.component.html#L2). Then the first loaded page is [the `login` page](https://github.com/NickIliev/nativescript-ng-cosmos/tree/master/app/pages/login). As the drawer is not needed, I am [explicitly hiding and disabling the drawer interaction in the code behind](https://github.com/NickIliev/nativescript-ng-cosmos/blob/master/app/pages/login/login.component.ts#L44-L45). To get a reference to my root drawer I am using `getRootView` method

```
import { getRootView } from "tns-core-modules/application";

// and later during the page initialization
this.drawer = <RadSideDrawer>getRootView();
this.drawer.gesturesEnabled = false;
```

The code in the links is for Angular based application but the concept is pretty much the same in NativeScript Core.

Comment: Thank you Nick.  Exactly what I needed.  One side note: Upon arriving at the next page, I had to call sideDrawer.gesturesEnabled = true; in order to re-enable the slide gesture.

Comment: After setting login page and persisting login. This does not work. `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'toggleDrawerState' of undefined` After redirecting from login page on oninit..drawer is undefined :(